# Regex matching Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem regex matching an upper case letter possibly followed by a lower case letter. I want to break after any such matches, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

To make it more general - I want to split before and after any matches in regex.

Example `string "TeSTString"`

Wanted result -> `[Te, S, T, St, ring]`

I have tried anything I can think of, but I'm getting tricked by look-ahead or behind.

First I tried `[A-Z][a-z]?`, and that matches perfect, but removes it...

result -> `[ring]`

after this I did positive look-ahead `(?=([A-Z][a-z]?))` giving me something close...

result -> `[Te, S, T, String]`

and look-behind `(<=?([A-Z][a-z]?))` giving nothing at all...

result -> `[TeSTString]`

even tried reversing the look-behind `(<=?([a-z]?[A-Z]))`, in a desperate attempt, but this was fairly unsuccessful.

Can anyone give a good pointer in the right direction before I lose my mind?

Comment: Why should `String` be split into `St` and `ring`?

Comment: Don't use split, you're going to have to do a regex search and manually build the array (or whatever) yourself.

Comment: @sp00m because that is the goal of my split? I'm sure I understand the question. I want to split off any ([A-Z][a-z]?), because I'm trying to make a custom simple tokenizer and parser.

Comment: @Necreaux I can see that working. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Will try that out if I can't find a way with split. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one convoluted pattern that will match the expected result.

```
String test = "TeSTStringOne";
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        //          | preceded by lowercase
        //          |        | followed by uppercase
        //          |        |       | or
        //          |        |       || preceded and followed by uppercase
        //          |        |       ||                  | or
        //          |        |       ||                  || preceded by uc
        //          |        |       ||                  || AND lowercase
        test.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z][a-z])")
    )
);
```

**Output**

```
[Te, S, T, St, ring, On, e]
```

**Note**

Replace `[a-z]` with `\\p{Ll}` and `[A-Z]` with `\\p{Lu}` to use with accented letters.

Comment: This works perfect. Bonus with the explanation!
Great many thanks to you Mena!

Comment: @Eric glad it works for you. I just removed the 1st part of the pattern by the way - it seemed redundant and yields the same output with the given test string.

Comment: The part was not redundant,  
TeSTStringOnE now gives 
Te S T St ringOn E

Comment: Which tool have you used to generate the explanation? Or have you done it manually?

Comment: @sp00m manually :( it's a pain but I don't like the automatic tools too much

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
(?<=[A-Z][a-z])|(?=(?<!^)[A-Z])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jM0gO8/1)

- `(?<=[A-Z][a-z])` = positive lookbehind for upper case followed by
  lower case,
- `(?=(?<!^)[A-Z])` - positive lookahead for upper case, if not preceded by beginnig of a line,

Comment: This seem to work as well! You guys are really fast and good at this!